# Nutrition farmed vs wild salmon

Tags: food-safety, fish

I read this link as well as watching the accompanying docmentary
http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2016/04/30/salmon-fish-farming.aspx 
and it makes farmed salmon look like something to be avoided at all costs.  Not only can it contain more chemicals but it can have additives and even a 1:1 omega 3 to omega 6 ratio.  On the other hand I've read articles where it says farmed salmon can have more omega 3 than wild even though it may have more omega 6.  In any case the lack of certification, bad practices and variations between farms make data on this quite murky?  I'm notonly asking about nutrition, but also about additives, chemicals, disease causing fish etc.  Is farmed salmon really so bad as the link makes out?  Would you avoid it. Also does it really have a 1:1 omega 3:6 ratio generally speaking. Your thoughts please.